# Wav file matching

Tags: audio-recording, field-recording, wav, matching, resources

Is there a way to find / match two same recordings from different sources by analyzing the waveform of selected sounds. I have to find same recordings for reference purposes but nothing is labeled and there are too many files to do it manually in one day (time I have left).

Answer (score 4):

How is your coding? You could put together this functionality using an acoustic fingerprint library such as http://acoustid.org/chromaprint

Comment: Or use one of the existing services - such as SoundHound - that provides acoustic fingerprint matching. It's only as fast as you can play through the tracks though.

Comment: I assumed you needed to do a lot of files really fast. The method I suggested takes only milliseconds to id a file, even works on audio in video files. I might actually build this tool if there is a need.

Comment: i think that would be an excellent idea- build away!

Answer (score 4):

If you use or have access to a mac, [Similarity](http://www.similarityapp.com) should be able to help with this. The free version may be sufficient for your needs.

From the site:

> Similarity rapidly scans your music collection and shows all duplicate
>   music files you may have. The comparison powered by "acoustic
>   fingerprint" technology considers the actual contents of files, not
>   just tags or filenames, and thus ensures the extreme accuracy of
>   similarity estimation. Moreover, the comparison isn’t dependent of
>   music file format; the application supports almost every file format
>   in full.